# Pyramid - I have to run python setup.py install before changes register

Tags: python, configuration, pyramid, pycharm

I am just starting learning Pyramid using Pycharm.  I have been reading tutorials but unfortunately there don't seem to be many out there. 
My problem is that whenever I make a change to the source I have to run `python setup.py install` before I can test my changes. This step seems unnecessary and I am confused why this is the case.
I am developing in Pycharm on Windows. I would like to be able to change the code, restart the server, and see my changes reflected on the site immediately (skipping the distutils step).

Comment: Just in case you want more pyramid tutorials: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove all the installed bits in Python site-packages and run `python setup.py develop` to create a symlink (or .egg-link) to your project in site-packages, instead of the actual installed package. This should make your changes work as usual, without running `install` all the time.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer. Is this a distutils thing or a pyramid thing? I love Python but the deployment tools are sometimes confusing to me.

Comment: I'm not sure, it might be something Pycharm does silently. Normally distutils and the like do not install your project to site-packages.

Comment: I wasn't running the install from pycharm, but the command line. Pyramid is meant to work with distutils based on the available scaffolds. After your comment I realized what I was looking for and here are the relevant [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html).  My issue was that I didn't realize the problem was with the installation step - I thought it was with the configuration of the server.

Comment: echo “$(pwd)\n.” > venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/[project_name].egg-link

Answer (score 0):

I recently published three video tutorials of how to get started with Pyramid in PyCharm.

- [Pyramid in PyCharm in Five Minutes (Python
  2.7)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnX6AtNNoa4)
- [Pyramid in PyCharm in 5 minutes (Python
  3.3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO52-x2nJ_w)
- ["Hello World" in Pyramid using PyCharm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoJd2juXmfk)

The "Hello World" example shows a specific example of what you would like to do using a manual method, whereas the other two videos use a setting in `develop.ini` that automatically reloads changes to templates and other files (do not do this in production, obviously).

In addition, the master branch of the Pyramid documentation introduces a [Quick Tour](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tour.html) with detailed and revised [installation instructions for all OSes](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tutorial/requirements.html) that have been thoroughly tested in tutorials and hack nights (including those I have conducted for SFPython Meetup Hack Nights and PyLadiesSF South Bay Meetups).

Comment: Hey Steve, these are great resources and just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For configuration management you can use [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/solutions/configuration-management) or [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). In your case, you possibly could write a simple script that would check if there is change in an existing source folder, and then rebuild the software. (you could automate it using task scheduler in windows).

In the script:

```
if (Check if there are changes in folder):
  rebuild();
  redeploy();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Does that mean it is impossible to just test a pyramid app without running the installation step?